# Can our web site's custom CSS styles be applied within Rich Text fields?

Tags: cme, format-area-styles

Is there a way to set a CSS stylesheet to be applied to RTF fields in the Tridion Content Manager GUI?  We'd like to apply our basic paragraph and header styles so that users can see them as they are creating content.

Version: Tridion 2011 SP1

Bonus points:
We have separate stylesheets for separate publications. Can CSS within Rich Text fields be specified based on Publication ID?

[image: Example Content Manager Window]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed add stylesheets to be used by Tridion, see details in [LiveContent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_8495FD06A47D4418A41A32D2A714430F) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

You can then restrict **per field** which styles can be used by using the "Edit Formatting Features" button in the Schema Editor screen.

You will not be able to specify different styles for the same field in different blueprint contexts - the same rules apply to the same field anywhere in the blueprint.

Answer (score 8):

[As Nuno says](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3169/71), you cannot allow different classes to be available based on the position within the BluePrint context.

You can configure which styles are available for each rich text field within each separate Schema though.

You can do this by:

1. Open the Schema
2. Select the rich text field you want to control the styles on (e.g. 'Body text')
3. Click on the 'Edit Formatting Features' button
4. In the pop-up, select the 'Allowed Styles' tab
5. You should now be able to choose the styles that can be used for that field

It is also worth noting that you will need to clear your browser cache to pick up any changes to the styling used.

Hope this helps!